# How can I find a gitk type of tool for hg

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

Can you please tell me where I can find a 'gitk' type of tool for hg on ubuntu?

I have tried '$ sudo apt-get install tortoisehg' but I get this:

```
$ hgtk
abort: This version of TortoiseHg requires Mercurial version 1.3.n to 1.4.n, but finds 1.5.2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an extension called [hgk](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgkExtension) which looks very similar to gitk and distributed with recent versions of hg - you often need only to edit your `.hgrc` to enable it - though it's only really a visualisation and patch browsing tool and doesn't let you make anywhere near as many changes as gitk. (Personally, I prefer [hgview](http://www.logilab.org/project/hgview) which looks a lot better though is again only really for visualisation and patch browsing.)

Comment: How can I fix this error "pyrcc4: not found" and "/bin/sh: asciidoc: not found" on ubuntu 10.04

Comment: If you type pyrcc4 at the command prompt, you get a helpful message suggesting a package to install to get it. Same goes for asciidoc.

Comment: add `hgk =` to your .hgrc, launch with `hg view`

Answer (score 3):

Please [download and install hgtk](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/linux.html) directly. The TortoiseHg project keeps their code compatible with the last two Mercurial releases, so it's quite easy to make it work if your package is too old.